# How do I set up bridges and vlans with netplan

Tags: networking, virtualization, ethernet, netplan

I'm trying to ready my network for running some VMs. As far as I could read, the way to go is to create a bunch of bridges from my physical ethernet interface (perhaps even bond the two I have?), and a  bunch of vlans. Again, from what I could read, would it be something like:

1. Br0 - Main bridge, used by Ubuntu base OS.
2. BrX - Several other bridges, each associated with a vlan, each used for one (or more?) VM(s).

Is that correct, and a sensible way to proceed for both running some stuff directly in the base Ubuntu OS, and running a bunch of VMs? And if so, how do I actually do this? Preferably where the "main" bridge inherits the MAC from the physical interface.

I've seen a bunch of guides, but they all differ in how they set it up, so I'm a bit confused. Also, none of them refer to the same file I have in `/etc/netplan/`. I only have a `00-installer-config.yaml` (but I think it doesn't really matter what it's called, right?) with the following:

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

I'm running Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 LTS.

Comment: You can find some info at: https://ostechnix.com/install-and-configure-kvm-in-ubuntu-20-04-headless-server/. If you have only on nic on host, you may configure a bridge for that and use that bridge on all your VMs. If you have more than 1 nics and each is in a different network, then i guess you are going to have to have a bridge for every nic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't "need" to have a bridge for the host, you can continue to use the interface as is, create vlans on it and define bridges connected to those vlans.

The official documentation on [netplan examples](https://netplan.io/examples/#configuring-network-bridges) lists how to set up those vlan-bridges with netplan and how to use them later in libvirt.

That is "a" way to go, depending on your overall scope and later demand for features you can consider replacing basic bridges with [OpenVswitch](https://docs.openvswitch.org/en/latest/howto/kvm/) instead which has [VLANs as well](https://docs.openvswitch.org/en/latest/howto/vlan/), but also much more features (at the price of a more complex setup).

Comment: I think the vlan is the way to go. Way better than what I was doing before at least. OpenVswitch is probably more than I need atm, but I'll keep it in the back of my mind. Thanks!