# How do I configure a vlan-linked bridge in netplan to serve a VM?

Tags: networking, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, netplan

My problem is basically that, when trying to use a bridge on a vlan interface, I don't have network to my VM, and I'm not sure what I'm missing.

I have tried the setup detailed in the [examples](https://netplan.io/examples/#configuring-network-bridges). As well as numerous other guides. This is my current netplan `.yaml` (though I've tried various combinations of defining `addresses`, `gateway4`, and `nameservers` for the vlan or the bridge with no luck):

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: true
    eno2:
      dhcp4: true
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: true
      interfaces: [ vlan15 ]
      parameters:
        forward-delay: 0
        stp: true
  vlans:
    vlan15:
      id: 15
      link: eno1
```

I'd like to keep `eno2` untouched, so I always have a fallback (no monitor attached). In my DHCP server, I have set eno1 = 192.168.0.100, and eno2 = 192.168.0.101.

My LAN in the router is set to 192.180.0.0/22 (I was trying to through VMs in the 192.168.1.x range, but not essential).

I have set up the bridge, and activated it:

```
~$ brctl show
bridge name bridge id           STP enabled interfaces
br0         8000.00215ec64304   yes         vlan15
                                            vnet0
```

(I'm almost certain that the `vnet0` wasn't associated until I booted the VM)

and

```
~$ virsh net-list --all
 Name      State    Autostart   Persistent
--------------------------------------------
 br0       active   yes         yes
 default   active   yes         yes
```

`ip a` shows both `br0` and `vlan15` linked to the MAC of `eno1`. In the .xml file for the VM (`/etc/libvirt/qemu/hassos.xml`), it shows under "interface":

```
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:26:69:40'/>
      <source bridge='br0'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x01' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
```

I initially set this up with `br0` being linked directly to `eno1`, so I did the `virt-install` before I started to create vlan, in case that matters. But I have rebooted the VM whenever i do `sudo netplan apply`.

The closest I could get (which is not really close, just something happened) was that when I defined a `addresses: 192.168.1.115` on the `br0`, I could access something on the server using this address, and the corresponding port. Just not the VM (but a "clone" running in docker, directly on the server). In that case it seems like `br0` was then used for anything on the server?

I'm using Ubuntu Server LTS 20.04.

In case this matters, I have (according to other advise) disabled netfilter for bridges as described e.g. [here](https://jamielinux.com/docs/libvirt-networking-handbook/bridged-network.html#initial-steps).

EDIT: I set up the bridge for libvirt by creating an br0.xml file:

```
<network>
  <name>br0</name>
  <forward mode="bridge"/>
  <bridge name="br0"/>
</network>
```

And added it with:

```
virsh net-define br0.xml
virsh net-start br0
virst net-autostart br0
```

I've also tried more complex .xml files such as

```
<network>
  <name>br1</name>
  <forward mode='nat'>
    <nat>
      <port start='1024' end='65535'/>
    </nat>
  </forward>
  <bridge name='br1' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <ip address='192.168.1.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='192.168.1.101' end='192.168.1.150'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

And with the 192.168.**1**.X addresses, I an get it to assign in IP from within libvirt, but I can't get access externally. If I instead use a 192.168.**0**.X address, I get erros when trying to start it:

```
error: Failed to start network br1
error: internal error: Network is already in use by interface eno2
```

This is regardless of setting an 192.168.**0**.X IP within or outside DHCP pool, and regardless of setting 192.168.**1**.X IP as a DHCP assignment or not.

Comment: Please check this URL: https://ostechnix.com/install-and-configure-kvm-in-ubuntu-20-04-headless-server/ . Looks like it is explained there. Otherwise, I can help you tomorrow in detail.

Comment: I had something like that set up, but that uses a bridge directly on the ethernet interface (`eno1`). That worked, but then the bridge got the IP of `eno1`, and `eno1` no longer had an IP. I was recommended to use a vlan, and add the bridge to that, so I could continue using the `eno1` normally for everything else. And that's where I got stuck....

Comment: I see. That goes a little bit beyond my network knowledge. I'm going to let you know if I can find any tips, sorry.

Comment: Thanks, please do. It's certainly also beyond my network knowledge...

Comment: Hi, how did you setup/activate the bridge "br0"? Usually netplan does that for you and there might be conflicts if you do it manually. Also, you're using DHCP for br0 and eno1, while they have the same MAC address... This might confuse your DHCP server. You could try defining another MAC for one of those devices via a "macaddress: ..." setting.

Comment: I edited my question to include the activation (in libvirt) of the bridge. I for both have now tried setting `macaddress` for `br0` in the netplan .yaml (different MAC than for `eno1`), but still no luck.
Would that mean that I can just delete bridges, and have netplan create automatically? How would that work (no bridge was available for libvirt before setting up in netpan)?

Comment: This question at this time might be silly, sorry about that. Do you have 2 network interfaces?

Comment: @NK_ I have two physical network interfaces (`eno1` and `eno2`) on my Ubuntu machine, if that's what you mean? Each with an ethernet cable attached, and each accessible via their respective IPs, `192.168.0.100` and `192.168.0.101`, set in my DHCP server (well, I actually have `eno2` IP configured in netplan atm, but same IP as before when I managed in DHCP server).
And don't be sorry, I'll take any brainstorming at this point; I'm thoroughly stuck :)

Comment: I know what you mean :) I'm reading a book about KVM and I'm at the networking part now. I believe your problem can be solved, but I just need a little bit understanding of the subject. I'm going to sleep with it tonight, and I hope I'm going to return with some answers tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I (almost) replicated your situation.

Both network interfaces of my server are connected to my router. My workstation is connected to the same router.

Configurations:

**Server (Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS):**

1. Interface: 192.168.0.240
2. Interface: 192.168.0.241

Bridge (br0) on VLAN which is on 1. Interface: 192.168.100.1

*Netplan File on the server:*

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0f0:
      addresses: [ 192.168.0.240/24 ]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [ 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4 ]
    enx00e04c534458:
      addresses: [192.168.0.241/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,4.4.4.4]
  bridges:
    br0:
      addresses: [ 192.168.100.1/24 ]
      interfaces: [ vlan100 ]
  vlans:
    vlan100:
      accept-ra: no
      id: 100
      link: enp3s0f0
```

I am not sure if it is really necessary, but to make the server to route between its interfaces (remember I was connecting to 2 different networks before), I made the following configuration.

Add following line to /etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Run:

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

**VM (Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS):**

When installing the VM with virt-install, it couldn't get the IP address automatically, so I entered manually as:

subnet: 192.168.100.0/24
ip: 192.168.100.101
gateway: 192.168.100.1

VM could not connect to the internet, but installed succesfully.

*Generated netplan file of the VM:*

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.100.101/24
      gateway4: 192.168.100.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
  version: 2
```

After installation, I was able to access to the VM on the server, but I couldn't access it from my workstation. It looked like a routing problem. So I added a route.

**Workstation (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS):**

Single interface with 2 IPs. 192.168.0.242 and 192.168.0.243

*Netplan file on the workstation:*

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.0.242/24,192.168.0.243/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [46.197.15.60,178.233.140.110,176.240.150.250]
      routes:
      - to: 192.168.100.0/24
        via: 192.168.0.240
```

The last 3 lines adds a route to 192.168.100.0 network, through the server's interface.

After all these configurations, I am able to connect to the VM from my workstation.
If I need to connect to the Vm from any other computer in my network, I need to add that routing information to them too.

---

### The old answer, to be deleted later

I don't have 2 ethernet cards, so I am not able to test it, but I believe this method would possibly run. I believe you can do it without using a VLAN. At least it is something to try.

Make your netplan file as one nic configured as standart and the other one is configured as a bridge (without DHCP just to be sure), feel free to change the IP and nameservers as you wish :

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: no
    eno2:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [ 192.168.0.100/24 ]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [ 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4 ]
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: no
      interfaces: [ en01 ]
      addresses: [ 192.168.0.101/24 ]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      mtu: 1500
      nameservers:
        addresses: [ 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4 ]
      parameters:
        forward-delay: 4
        stp: true
```

Disable netfilter, add the bridge to KVM (I believe you already did them)

---

As said in the comment, a working netplan config with vlan:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp3s0f0:
      addresses: [192.168.0.240/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
    enx00e04c534458:
      addresses: [10.1.1.1/24]
      gateway4: 10.1.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,4.4.4.4]
  vlans:
    vlan10:
      id: 10
      link: enp3s0f0
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [ vlan10 ]
      addresses: [192.168.1.240/24]
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking into this. And I really don't want to sound ungrateful, but this is sort of what I currently have. This works OK, but I was recommended to keep the `eno1` functioning "as is" by _"creating vlans on it and define bridges connected to those vlans"_ (actually [an answer to another question I had where you also made a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1302191/how-do-i-set-up-bridges-and-vlans-with-netplan/1304936#1304936)). So after that answer, I tried the vlan, it didn't work, I did the bridge without vlan, but then got stubborn, and asked about vlan here :)

Comment: I see and understand your point. A good computer specialist must be stabborn always. Your stabborness is my stabborness :) I'll be around until one of us solve this situation, if that is ok with you, of course. I've bought a usb lan adapter to use as a second nic.

Comment: Thanks a lot, just stop _before_ you go crazy :) I'm not sure if two physical interfaces would be necessary, as I understood it, the point of the vlan instead of "just" bridge was that you could continue to use the physical interface for everything it was used for before. I might be wrong, but that was my understanding.

Comment: I guess I've found something. The reason your configuration does not run is, your VLAN and your original nic is in the same network. I've added a configuration I made at the end of my answer. When I configured a VLAN with another subnet, it worked. But the problem here is, all my VMs will be in another subnet.

Comment: Also, as you said it looks like 2 physical interfaces are not necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I think there's at least progress :) I can certainly get the bridge to show up on the `192.168.1.101` address with `eno1` on `192.168.0.100` (and `eno2` at `192.168.0.101`). I can still access both my physical interfaces (ssh), but my VM does not appear. If I try accessing the service in the VM via the bridge IP (`192.168.1.101:8123`) the same service I have in running in docker shows up, not the one in the VM :/
I tried setting a DHCP reservation (`192.168.1.115`) for the VM, but that doesn't happen.
Is it important that `enp3s0f0` and `enx00e04c534458` are on separate networks?

Comment: enx... is my usb network interface, I couldn't be able to connect it to my network (cable problems). I don't think it is important to them to be on separate networks. I guess you have a docker container, is it on the host or on the VM? Do you think it is a routing problem between 192.168.0 and 192.168.1 networks?

Comment: The docker container is on the host. The VM is going to replace the docker container, and it's basically the same(ish) service, accessible via web interface on port 8123. I thought it was something about the routing, but not sure what. I can access the bridge (192.168. **1** .101) from computers on the 192.168. **0** .X network. I've set my LAN to 192.168.0.1/22 in router, and tried using DHCP to either give addresses in 192.168.0.2 - 192.168.0.240 or 192.168.0.2. - 192.168. **1** .240. And/or setting DHCP reservations for either 192.168. **0** .115 or 192.168. **1** .115 for the VM.

Comment: The routing problem might be on the VM itself. Can you check if its default gateway is your bridge's IP?

Comment: I think I replicated your situation, I'm sharing my configs at the start of the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try over the weekend when I have a few moments. I have to add routing info in the VM and on each device that wants to connect to the VM? I'm not sure this is possible in the VM. At least, it's likely to be overwritten on each update, and I will only have access to the terminal though a webUI add-on **after** the VM is up and running and accessible online. Other devices only need access to web UI, but they are a mix of MacOS, Windows, and mobile (Android and iOS) apps/browsers. Not all are my devices, so I don't think I can add networking info to all of those.

Comment: Uou may not have to add routing to the VM. But it looks like you have to add routing to the other devices which needs to connect to the VM. Or, there might be a solution on the network devices (switches, routers), but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Sorry for the delay... I've been trying a bit, but I can't seem to get network access to the VM. Without access to it without (e.g. via VNC), I don't think I will with my current setup. However, that's likely (as you say) a networking issue, and was not part of my original question. Thus, while I cannot verify myself, I do think you have answered the question (and thanks a lot for the work!). I'll continue to try finding the solution for my (new) problem. I'll come back to this once my new networking hardware arrives!

Comment: No problem at all. I'm studying on KVM and QEMU and I thought your situation would have been a good challenge, and actually it was. As I said before, unfortunately I am not so good at networking, but I am always here to help about KVM.